# Google Closure Compiler: How to preserve code that caches "this"?

Tags: javascript, this, google-closure-compiler

## Introduction

I use Google Closure Compiler frequently for compressing my JavaScript files. Now, it seems to compress my code fairly well.

Now, I try to make a habit of storing the `this` object in a local variable, because `this` cannot be obfuscated, but a local variable certainly can be obfuscated. However, Google Closure Compiler does not recognize this, and instead removes all instances of the local variable, replacing it with `this`.

#### Regarding optimization...

I am well aware that one should avoid pre-optimization when writing code. However, I feel that caching `this` is acceptable because doing so provides clarity (because `this` can have many contexts, and referencing it by another name will reduce ambiguity).

## Example

The code below is pretty basic, and I understand that it may be poorly written. However, the code will demonstrate exactly the issue which I am facing.

Here is the original source file, before compression:

```
(function() {
  var that = this;
  that.a = 3;
  that.b = 4;
  this.c = 5;
  return that;
}());
```

Now here is the compressed source file. Note that the assignment of `this` to `that` has been removed.

```
(function(){this.a=3;this.b=4;this.c=5;return this})();
```

Ideally, I would expect the assignment to `that` to remain in some form, perhaps something similar to this:

```
(function(){var t=this;t.a=3;t.b=4;t.c=5;return t})();
```

Now, the code above hardly saves any bytes, but when working with a much larger script (as I often do), the savings most definitely add up.

## Question

In short, how can I prevent the Closure Compiler from removing the `that` variable in my above script?

Comment: Why do you care? it's about 5-10bytes and doesn't effect anything, keep walking.

Comment: Good question, but why do you use that variable in the original source code at all? Is it only for obfuscation?

Comment: I assign `this` to a variable because it provides clarity. After all, `this` has many contexts, so referencing it by another name reduces ambiguity.

Comment: If you do it for clarity, why do you care it is removed after optimization?

Comment: You make a good point; I suppose I just wonder about these things. In that case, I don't need any more help. Thanks for the rationale. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to out-think the compiler. It's a losing battle. However, here's the two main reasons people try to do this type of thing.

1. Reduce size of code. The theory being that a single letter variable is smaller than the keyword `this`. However, this theory is flawed in most cases. See [the compiler FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#Closure_Compiler_inlined_all_my_strings,_which_made_my_code_size).
2. Prevent the context of the keyword `this` from changing. However, in SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS this is unnecessary. If you create an inner closure that references your variable, the compiler will not inline the value. Under ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS, using the keyword `this` can be dangerous outside of a prototype function or constructor and should be done with care. See [an article explaining why](http://closuretools.blogspot.com/).

If you really want to prevent the compiler from inlining your value, you'll need to add it as a property on an object using  quoted syntax:

```
(function() {
  var config = {};
  config['that'] = this;
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if you really have to you could do this:

```
(function() {
  var that = this || 1;
  that.a = 3;
  that.b = 4;
  this.c = 5;
  return that;
}());
```